# May a non-Jew who has not undergone gerus teach Torah to Jews?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism

Shalom.

I recently gave answer on Mi Yodeya here:

[Does coming to God near death count less than coming to God when times are good?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/131056/does-coming-to-god-near-death-count-less-than-coming-to-god-when-times-are-good)

I took a chance on this. I wasn't sure this was lawful. As explained there, I am a non-Jew pursuing conversion (I am in conversation with my local Beis Din).

Can anyone tell me if I sinned here? Is it lawful for a non-Jew who has not undergone gerus to teach / give Torah to a Jew?

Many thanks.

Comment: Teaching is learning intensely. I would imagine whatever he can learn he can teach.

Comment: I know of another person in the process of going through geirus who is teaching Torah to Jews and non-Jews with the approval of London Beth Din

Comment: @wizzardmr42 - B"H, many thanks for this information :)

Comment: @TomW If I were you, I'd still discuss it with the Rabbi who you are learning with at least, if not the Beth Din that you are converting under.  Good luck with getting through the process - I have great respect for anyone who wants to do so!

Comment: @wizzardmr42 - will do, many thanks. Shanah tovah if I do not hear from you :)

Comment: @TomW Shana tova u'mesukah!

Comment: @wizzardmr42 - :) amen!